# Function explode() after x characters, not punctuation

Tags: php

I'm creating an application where the user is suppose to type a text as correctly as possible. The text is coming from a database and its placed in a string. I'm displaying the string in a `div` and if the length of the string is to long for the `div` I want to split it. I know there have been similar questions before, but I haven't found a solution to my problem.

This is what I'm trying to do:

Atm this happens:

```
--------------------
| The displayed str|ing 
--------------------
```

And I want this:

```
--------------------
| The displayed st | 
--------------------
```

This is my code so far:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $textline = explode(".", $row["text"]);
}

$i = 0;

foreach ($textline as $o) {
   $letters = str_split_unicode($letters[$i], 1);
   if (ctype_space($letters[0])) {
         unset($letters[0]);
   }
   foreach ($letters as $l) {
      if (ctype_space($l)) {
         echo "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
      } else {
        echo "<p>$l</p>";
      }
   }
            $i++;
}
```

To sum up: I want to split the string after 'x' characters, NOT on '.' as it is now

//edit:

The code splits the text splits at punctuation, but I want it to split after "x" characters

Now it splits like this:

> ```
> This is a sentence. 
> This is another sentence. 
> This is a third sentence.
> ```

But I want it to split like this:

> ```
> This is a sent
> ence. This is 
> another senten
> ce. This is a 
> third sentence
> .
> ```

Here it splits after 14 characters (including space).

Comment: The way you illustrate the problem, `overflow: hidden;`, in the CSS for that/those `div` element(s) would do just as well; am I missing something? [Simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pxQHM/).

Comment: Using CSS overflow:hidden isn't an option? It would take care of font size issues for you, which would be hard to do with PHP.

Comment: the `overflow:hidden` is great, and works very well, but the way the code works is that the text is split into different "textlines", and with `overflow:hidden` the rest of the text just disappears

Comment: Have you looked at [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the str_split_unicode() function that's mentioned on the page you are referring to

Comment: _“The code splits the text splits at punctuation”_ – well if you don’t want that – then why the heck are you _explicitly_ doing it via `explode` …?

Comment: And your code as shown doesn’t make sense, it is trying to access `$letters[$i]` in the first line of the foreach loop, but that variable has not been given a value before.

Comment: Because this is the way the code is now, but I want to change it so it splits after 'x' characters, not on punctuation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this will work. Replace this code:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
$textline = explode(".", $row["text"]); 
}
```

With this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$string = $row['text']; $string = wordwrap($string, 80, ";;;;", true); 
$oppgavelinjer = explode(";;;;", $string); 
}
```

As long as the text doesnt contain 4 semi-colons in a row you're good Replace '80' with the length you want

Comment: Thank you sooooo much, been stuck on this for hours